# DDWRT access IP over NAT

Tags: nat, dd-wrt

I have Wi-Fi router with DDWRT and a fileserver over router's NAT.

How can I access a fileserver from the router's subnet ?

A computer is connected to a Wi-Fi router its IP starts with 192, Wi-Fi router is connected to a LAN the same as fileserver, the fileserver has IP that starts with 172. How to configure DDWRT to allow computer to access the fileserver ?

Comment: More information, please.

Comment: A computer is connected to a wifi router its IP starts with 192, wifi router is connected to a LAN the same as fileserver, the fileserver has IP that starts with 172. How to configure DDWRT to allow computer to access the fileserver ?

Answer (score -1):

The IP address that starts with `172` is a
[private network address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network),
meaning that the file-server has allocated its own address.

In other words, the file-server has not managed to contact the router for
getting a network IP address via DHCP.

You will need to check why that is happening, but until the file-server really
participates in the network, it cannot be accessed from other devices.

If for some reason the file-server cannot ask the router for the IP address,
but is still clearly connected to it, you may assign it a static IP address
that has the same prefix as the rest of the network.

To avoid conflicts arising from devices with duplicate IP, ensure also that the
router will not assign this IP address.
Adjusting the router's setting for the DHCP allocation range, so as to exclude
this static IP, would avoid such duplication.

Comment: Why this downvote?